# Layer backed NSView problems in viewDidLoad

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I set off to transform an NSImageView. My initially attempt was

```
self.imageView.wantsLayer = YES;
self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1,1,1,1);
```

Unfortunately I noticed that the transform only happens *sometimes* (maybe once every 5 runs). Adding an NSLog between confirmed that on some runs `self.imageView.layer` is null. State of the whole project is shown on the image below.

[image: Project state]

It's an incredibly simple 200x200 NSImageView with an outlet to a generated NSViewController. Some experimentation showed settings wantsDisplay doesn't fix the problem, but putting the transform on an NSTimer makes it work every-time. I'd love an explanation why this happens (I presume it's due to some race condition).

I'm using Xcode 8 on the macOS 10.12 but I doubt this is the cause of the problem.

**Update**

Removing `wantsLayer` and madly enabling Core Animation Layers in Interface Builder did not fix the problem.

[image: Ticked core animation layers]

Neither did attempts to animate it (I wasn't sure what I was hoping for)

```
// Sometimes works.. doesn't animate
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.duration = 1;
    self.imageView.animator.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1,1,1,1);
} completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

or

```
// Animates but only sometimes
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(1,1,1,1)];
animation.duration = 1;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with allowsImplicitAnimation I realised I might be trying to animate too early.

Moving the transform code into `viewDidAppear` made it work every time.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];
    self.imageView.animator.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1,1,1,1);
}
```